# Pattern match on records with option type entries in OCaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

basically I have defined a record type like this:

```html
and exp = Bil_t.exp = {
  var: var option;
  binop: binop option;
  load: load option;
  store: store option;
  cast: cast option;
  inte: inte option;
  let_exp: let_exp option
}
```

And I am thinking to use a pattern match to process it, something like this:

```
match rexp with
    | {None;binop;None;None;None;None;None} -> trans_binop @@ strip binop
    | {var;None;None;None;None;None;None} -> BU.inte_to_string @@ strip @@ mark inte
    | _ -> failwith "undefined"
```

Sorry for the messy code above. So basically I compile the above code, and I get the error:

```
Error: Syntax error
```

Could anyone give me some help on this.. I just don't know what is wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record patterns need to include the field names.

```
type exp = {
  var: int option;
  binop: int option;
  load: int option;
  store: int option;
  cast: int option;
  inte: int option;
  let_exp: int option
}

let f rexp =
    match rexp with
    | { var = None; binop = Some b; load = None; store = None;
        cast = None; inte = None; let_exp = None
      } -> b
    | _ -> failwith "undefined"
```

Example:

```
# let r = { var = None; binop = Some 14; load = None; store = None; 
            cast = None; inte = None; let_exp = None };;
val r : exp =
  {var = None; binop = Some 14; load = None; store = None; cast = None;
   inte = None; let_exp = None}
# f r;;
- : int = 14
```

Comment: As a minor addendum, you can drop the *value pattern* instead: `{var; binop; load; store; cast; inte; let_exp}`. This will give you a bunch of bound variables called `var`, `binop`, and so on. Of course, this is not what you need for your code, but FYI.

Comment: Yes, this is a useful abbreviation a lot of the time and good to know about. Instead of writing `{ a = a; b = b }` you can just write `{ a; b }`.

Comment: @antron, thank you antron. But to my understanding, you still have to check these 7 variables' option, right?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to see whether the values you got are `None`, you would have to do additional checks. It's better done directly in the pattern, as in Jeffrey Scofield's answer. My comment is only for when you just want to bind a name to a record field, without pattern matching on the value's structure. You also have to be ok with getting a variable that has the same name as the record field.